How to retry a failed JUnit 5 test based on if a specific exception was thrown in Kotlin
Problem:
I have some JUnit 5 integration tests that sometimes fail due to transient errors, specifically throwing a MySpecificException.
I need these tests to retry up to 3 times if MySpecificException is thrown, but fail immediately if a different exception is thrown.

What I Tried:
I attempted to implement a retry rule by using the TestRule interface as suggested in this Stack Overflow answer:

How to Re-run failed JUnit 4 tests immediately

Unfortunately, the solution provided in the above thread related to TestRule is not compatible with JUnit 5.

Ask:

How to implement a retry mechanism that retries failed tests with MySpecificException up to 3 times in JUnit 5 using Kotlin?

How can I make this retry mechanism applicable both at the test class level and at the test method level? For example:
// Test Class Scope
@RetryMechanism(MySpecificException::class, retries = 3)
class MyTests {
    @Test
    fun testSomething() {
        assertEquals(x, obj.doX())
    }
}

// Test Method Scope
class MyTests {
    @Test
    @RetryMechanism(MySpecificException::class, retries = 3)
    fun testSomething() {
        assertEquals(x, obj.doX())
    }
}




How about this SO Q&A: JUnit5: How to repeat failed test?

There's JUnit Pioneer (disclaimer: I'm a maintainer), which comes with @RetryingTest:
@RetryingTest(maxAttempts = 3, onExceptions = MySpecificException.class)

If you want to implement your own solution, feel free to check out the sources (Eclipse Public License v2).
